# Python regex: parsing newick format

Tags: python, regex

I have a string like:

```
(A\2009_2009-01-04:0.2,(A\name2\human\2007_2007:0.3,A\chicken\ird16\2016_20016:0.4)A\name3\epi66321\2001_2001-04-04:0.5)A\name_with_space\2014_2014:0.1)A\name4\66036-8a\2004_2004-12-05;
```

In this tree, *names* are enclosed on the left by either an open bracket "(", a closing bracket ")", or a comma, and enclosed on the right with a colon ':'. That is, the substrings "A\2009_2009-01-04", "A\name2\human\2007_2007", "A\name3\epi66321\2001_2001-04-04", are names. (this is actually a tree in newick format).

I'd like to find a regex pattern which **finds all names, with as little restriction on namespace as possible**. Think of names as variables, like this example from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newick_format):

`(A:0.1,B:0.2,(C:0.3,D:0.4)E:0.5)F;`

Where A, B, C etc. can be any string. The only restriction on namespace is that names cannot contain rounded or square brackets, '&', ',' or ':', because these are special characters that define the tree format, the same way that the comma defines a csv format.

Bonus: sometimes, internal nodes within the tree aren't labelled:

`(A:0.1,B:0.2,(C:0.3,D:0.4):0.5);`

In which case, a regex that correctly returns a string of length zero would be great.

Comment: Do not use `|` in the place of “or” in the square brackets. The square brackets themselves mean “any in the list”. So the first part should look like `[\(\),]` to match “rounded brackets or a comma”.

Comment: @Melebius Almost correct, but it can be `[(),]`. When between brackets, special characters will be treated as literal characters.

Comment: Tried both, neither worked I'm afraid.

Comment: @AndreyIto I posted it as a comment because it’s a partial correction, not the solution of your entire problem. BTW, I recommend http://regex101.com/ for developing and testing complex regexes.

Comment: @AndreyIto Try `re.findall(r'[(),]([A-Za-z]\\[^\s:]+)\b', s)`. Or, if there are *forward slashes*, try `re.findall(r'[(),]([A-Za-z]/[^\s:]+)\b', s)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want to extract substrings that start with 1+ `(`, `)` or `,` and then contain 1+ non-whitespace characters other than `:` and `;`, as many as possible, but stop at the word boundary.

Use

```
r'[(),]+([^;:]+)\b'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/p0acn6/2).

**Pattern details**

- `[(),]+` - one or more characters in the character class: `(`, `)` or `,`
- `([^;:]+)` - Group 1: one or more chars other than `;` and `:`, as many as possible
- `\b` - a word boundary

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/YGaNn7):

```
import re
rx = r'[(),]+([^;:]+)\b'
s = "(A:0.1,B:0.2,(C:0.3,D:0.4)E:0.5)F;((A\\2009_2009-01-04:0.2,(A\\name2\\human\\2007_2007:0.3,A\\chicken\\ird16\\2016_20016:0.4)A\\name3\\epi66321\\2001_2001-04-04:0.5)A\\name_with_space\\2014_2014:0.1)A\\name4\\66036-8a\\2004_2004-12-05;"
res = re.findall(rx, s)
for val in res:
    print(val)
```

Output:

```
A
B
C
D
E
F
A\2009_2009-01-04
A\name2\human\2007_2007
A\chicken\ird16\2016_20016
A\name3\epi66321\2001_2001-04-04
A\name_with_space\2014_2014
A\name4\66036-8a\2004_2004-12-05
```

Comment: I eventually arrived at: `pattern = re.compile(r'[(),][\s\S]*?(?=:|;)')`. It sometimes still returns the enclosing special characters, though: e.g. the output for `(A:0.1,B:0.2,(C:0.3,D:0.4)E:0.5)F;` is `['(A', ',B', ',(C', ',D', ')', ')']`. Used `replace` to strip them out.

Comment: @AndreyIto: `r'[(),][\s\S]*?(?=:|;)'`  = `r'[(),][^:;]*'`.

Comment: @AndreyIto: See a better option. No need to postprocess the results. Please consider accepting if it works for you.

Comment: I've reaccepted it so that future users can either use your solution, or the general one I posted in the comments. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0):

you can use the regex

> (\w+)(?=:|;)

see the sample code

```
import re

regex = r"(\w+)(?=:|;)"

test_str = "((B:0.2,(C:0.3,D:0.4)E:0.5)F:0.1)A;"

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches):
    matchNum = matchNum + 1

    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))
```

The output is

> Match 1 was found at 2-3: B 
>   Match 2 was found at 9-10: C 
>   Match 3 was found at 15-16: D 
>   Match 4 was found at 21-22: E 
>   Match 5 was found at 27-28: F 
>   Match 6 was found at 33-34: A

Answer (score 0):

A working solution:

```
[(),]([A-E])(?!;)
```

See [live demo](https://regex101.com/r/GKpwSJ/2). One mistake you made was escaping characters inside the character class; but inside it they don't have special meaning.

I also took care of selecting against a trailing semicolon.

Answer (score 0):

```
pattern = re.compile(r'[(),]A/[\S]*?:')
```

Not the most elegant, because I made use of the fact that all my names start with "A/". This will not be true for future use cases, just this current one. Will leave this question open if someone can find a more generalizable solution.

Comment: See my answer for a more generic solution. Please feel free to leave a comment if it works or not for you.